# Is it possible to have a connection to LotusNotes and use it as a data source for a C# project?

Tags: c#, .net, datasource

Is it possible to have a connection to LotusNotes and use it as a data source for a C# project?

We use LN for email/calendar.  Management wants a web page that would interact with the calendar.  I think this can all be done within Notes, but I would much rather do it in .NET.

Some very specific functionality is wanted, some of which I'm not really sure can even be done in Notes.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's possible to *interact* with LN from C# because we've done it before.  We had to wrap their C++ API, but it worked.  Unfortunately, I don't have any code to share with you since I no longer work on that project.

I'm not certain what you mean by 'datasource', though.

Comment: @John: desktop and server applications are different. It may not be safe to call Notes from an ASP.NET page, as it is not safe to call Outlook, for instance.

Comment: By datasource I just meant data extracted from LN.  For example, the page contain events that come from LN calendar, so I would connect to Notes, get data and populate a datagrid, for instance.  Not sure this can be done because LN is not a relational db.

Answer (score 0):

Do you not have [iNotes](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/lotus/products/inotes/) installed on your mail environment?  I would look at using something that's already built instead of starting from scratch.

Comment: @Walter: yes, and that may be the way we are going to go.  However, there are some very specific requirements and that's the reason I though to have a custom page built. - Alex

Answer (score 0):

Have you investigated using the [ODBC driver for Notes](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/products/notesdomino/notessql/)? It exposes the Notes database as if it were relational.

In my experience, it doesn't perform very well, but if your database is small enough and the transactions few enough, it may suit your purpose.